# How to start pm2 without autosave logs

Tags: node.js, javascript

I start my nodejs app with pm2, all works, but it save expensive logs.

I don't know how to start without save logs, i want to save only error logs.

Thanks!

Comment: I do a stress test to my application, and i found in /.pm2/myapp-o-log with 2gb of log....i think is pm2 as logger...

Comment: You're right, I wasn't thinking clearly....

Comment: No one knows anything?

Comment: You are right. In the next release we are going to implement a `--no-logs` flag to avoid useless overhead for people who use their own logging system or don't want logs at all.